# react Navigation 3.x open drawer from header button?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to create a header on top with title for each screen and button on the right to open the drawer in react navigation 3.x

In the code below the header does not show.

//Updated with Current code

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createAppContainer
} from 'react-navigation';

import MyHomeScreen from './components/HomeScreen';
import MyNotificationsScreen from './components/ProfileScreen';

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: MyHomeScreen
    },
    Notifications: {
      screen: MyNotificationsScreen
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    navigationOptions: navigationOptionsHeader
  }
);

const navigationOptionsHeader = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    headerTitle: 'MY Home',
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
        title="Info"
        color="#222"
      />
    )
  };
};

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: What do you mean you are "showing two headers on top of each other"? What is the output of your code like? It would be great if you could write a minimal working example as an [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/) for us to verify.

Comment: the code that I have is not working obviously, I am trying to create a top header with icon that will open the drawer menu

Answer (score 7):

Use this inside your screen class

```
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
        title: 'Home',
        headerLeft: (
          < Icon name="menu" size={30} style={{marginStart:10}} backgroundColor="#000000" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} > < /Icon>
        ),
      };
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

**try this**

```
const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
      {
        Home: {
          screen: MyHomeScreen
        },
        Notifications: {
          screen: MyNotificationsScreen
        }
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'Home'
     navigationOptions: navigationOptionsHeader,

      }
    );


    const navigationOptionsHeader=({navigation})=>{


        return {

      headerRight: (
          <Button
            onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer();
    }
            title="Info"
            color="#222"
          />
        )
      };

    }
```

you can also add other stuffs in header like this

```
    const navigationOptionsHeader=({navigation})=>{


        return {

      headerRight: (
          <Button
            onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer();
    }
            title="Info"
            color="#222"
          />
        )

  headerLeft : <headerLeft/>,
  title: //Header Title
  headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#161616', height:48, },
  headerTitleStyle:{ color:'#cd9bf0', fontWeight: '400', alignSe
      };

    }
```

Comment: This does not work in react navigation V 3.x ... can you add the whole code?

Comment: @velvetInk did u ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

The `navigationoptions` had been renamed as `defaultNavigationOptions` in v3.

Please refer the documentation from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html

Comment: I am using a drawer navigator and none of these header options works for me in V3. Do you know if header options is specific to Stack Navigator?

Answer (score 2):

For React Navigation 5

Use the prop **options** as a function:

```
      <Stack.Screen
        name="screen name"
        component={ScreenComponent}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({ 
          headerRight: (props) => {
            return <Button onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer() }} />
          }
        })}
      />
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#configuring-the-navigator

Answer (score 1):

For react navigation 5.x

```
<Stack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={{
        headerLeft: () => (
          <View>
            <Icon
              onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
              name="menu"
            />
          </View>
        ),
      }}
/>
```